# How to trim white space from all elements in array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was just wondering what the best way to remove the white space from all the elements of a list would be.

For example if I had   `String [] array = {" String", "Tom Selleck "," Fish "}`
How could I get all the elements as `{"String","Tom Selleck","Fish"}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] trimmedArray = new String[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    trimmedArray[i] = array[i].trim();
```

Now `trimmedArray` contains the same strings as `array`, but without leading and trailing whitespace. Alternatively, you could write this for modifying the strings in-place in the same array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = array[i].trim();
```

Answer (score 32):

Another java 8 lambda option :

```
String[] array2 = Arrays.stream(array).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
```

And the ugly but optimized version without new array creation

```
Arrays.stream(array).map(String::trim).toArray(unused -> array);
```

Original "array" is modified.

Comment: The first one works great; the second didn't work for me because
`"Local variable array defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"`
In other words, array was being defined by java in a loop beginning with:
`for (String[] array; (array = reader.readNext()) != null;) {`

Answer (score 27):

Add commons-lang3-3.1.jar in your application build path.
Use the below code snippet to trim the String array.

```
String array = {" String", "Tom Selleck "," Fish "};
array = StringUtils.stripAll(array);
```

Answer (score 21):

In Java 8, `Arrays.parallelSetAll` seems ready made for this purpose:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, (i) -> array[i].trim());
```

This will modify the original array in place, replacing each element with the result of the lambda expression.

Comment: It would be great if the poster, or anyone, could give a clear explanation of why/how this works.

Comment: We have an array with some element with space like array[]={"AAA ","  BBB ","  CCC "} Then we use above java 8 feature and update the original array with following statement Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, (i) -> array[i].trim()); Now old array will have all element with no leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a really old post, but since Java 1.8 there is a nicer way to trim every String in an array.

Java 8 Lamda Expression solution:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
temp.forEach(e -> {temp.set((temp.indexOf(e), e.trim()});
yourArray = temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()]);
```

with this solution you don't have to create a new Array. 

Like in Óscar López's solution

Comment: Just a minor edit: `temp.forEach(e -> { temp.set(temp.indexOf(e), s.trim()); });`, otherwise it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: You're actually creating a new ArrayList _and_ a new array in the last line. There are much better ways to do this with Java 8, see the other answers. Also, doing an `indexOf` to find the index is terrible for performance, and will fail if there are duplicated elements!

Answer (score 4):

You can just iterate over the elements in the array and call `array[i].trim()` on each element

Comment: and remember to assign back to `array[i]`!!!! otherwise the iteration will have no effect.

Comment: You will have to store the trimmed strings somewhere, but not necessarily in `array[i]`. It might be better to store them in a second array, depending on OP's needs

Comment: His question [`to remove the white space from all the elements ...`] suggests he wants to override the current values with trimmed strings, so if this is indeed the case - you will need to store it back to `array[i]`

Answer (score 3):

For those (like me) who was looking for the same solution in Kotlin and were pointed to Java only - how to trim in Kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // array definition
    val array = arrayListOf<String>(" String", "Tom Selleck "," Fish ")
    println(array) // print original -> [ String, Tom Selleck ,  Fish ]

    // remove leading and trailing spaces, result is arrayList
    val sol1 = array.map { it.trim() }
    println("sol1 = $sol1") // -> sol1 = [String, Tom Selleck, Fish]

    // remove leading and trailing spaces, result is String
    val sol2 = array.joinToString { it.trim() }
    println("sol2 = $sol2") // -> sol2 = String, Tom Selleck, Fish
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how the OP happened to have `{" String", "Tom Selleck "," Fish "}` in an array in the first place (6 years ago), I thought I'd share what I ended up with.

My array is the result of using split on a string which might have extra spaces around delimiters. My solution was to address this at the point of the split. My code follows. After testing, I put splitWithTrim() in my Utils class of my project. It handles my use case; you might want to consider what sorts of strings and delimiters you might encounter if you decide to use it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(" abc def  ghi   jkl ", " ");
        test("  abc; def  ;ghi  ; jkl; ", ";");
    }

    public static void test(String str, String splitOn) {
        System.out.println("Splitting \"" + str + "\" on \"" + splitOn + "\"");
        String[] parts = splitWithTrim(str, splitOn);
        for (String part : parts) {
            System.out.println("(" + part + ")");
        }
    }

    public static String[] splitWithTrim(String str, String splitOn) {
        if (splitOn.equals(" ")) {
            return str.trim().split(" +");
        } else {
            return str.trim().split(" *" + splitOn + " *");
        }
    }
}
```

Output of running the test application is:

```
Splitting " abc def  ghi   jkl " on " "
(abc)
(def)
(ghi)
(jkl)
Splitting "  abc; def  ;ghi  ; jkl; " on ";"
(abc)
(def)
(ghi)
(jkl)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
String val = "hi hello prince";
String arr[] = val.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{   
     System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should provide, Why your code Works? Maybe the OP need aditional information.

Comment: @Purushottam, The question asked is `How to trim white space from all elements in array?`. Your answer does not trim the value, rather it replaces whitespace. In the question, you can see a word `"Tom Selleck "` after trim() it should be `"Tom Selleck"` and NOT `"TomSelleck"`. Hope you got the point/mistake.